# iOS use variable with another m file when button click change it

Tags: ios, variables, ios7

i need to change urlStr variable when my button clicked from another file. I'm writing my files; I explained everything i think too easy but hard for me please help me. 
Thanks a lot.

Request.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Request : NSObject{

}
```

Request.m file

```
      #import "Request.h"
      #import "MyViewController.h"


    static NSString * const urlStr = @"http://google.com";
// I WANT TO CHANGE THIS urlStr WHEN storebutton CLICKED 


    @interface Request () {
        BOOL reachable;
    }
```

MyviewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController{


}

@end
```

MyViewController.m file

```
#import "MyViewController.h"


@interface MyViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)storebutton
{
  NSString *urlStr = @"http://yahho.com"; // WHEN MY store button click action 

}

@end
```

Comment: It's `const`, so you cannot change it.

Comment: how can i change i think need some codes thanks not enough delete const.

Comment: You can't as it's `const`.  That means it's value cannot be changed.

Comment: Where do you create a `StoreRequest` object?

Comment: okay i deleted it but not change my my variable.  gives me Request.m:60:22: Use of undeclared identifier 'urlStr'

Comment: its name Request sorry i wrote wrong philipp

Comment: OK, let's change the question to, "Where do you create a `Request` object?"  (I mean `alloc` / `init`.)

Comment: @interface AnotherViewController () {
    
    Request *Request;
}

in another view controller

Comment: That doesn't create an object, just declares a pointer.  Also, if it's declared in `AnotherViewController`, `MyViewController` will need a reference to the object...how are the view controllers connected?

Comment: with afnnetwork2 have cell files etc.

Comment: Your response really isn't an answer.  Sorry, I give up.

Comment: which codes i need write here ill find its ?

Answer (score 0):

Make **urlStr** as static variable only, then create a static setter method for it inside Request.m and declare it in Request.h as shown below.

```
+ (void)setURLString:(NSString *) urlString
{
    urlStr = urlString;
}
```

call this method on done button press as

```
-(void)storebutton
{
  NSString *newURL = @"http://yahho.com";
  [Request setURLString:newURL];
}
```